# Credit Card Expiration: Am I supposed to request a new one or does the bank send one automatically?

Tags: credit-card, banking, expiration

I've had one credit card expire recently and another set to expire soon. For the one that did expire, I didn't get another card until I wrote to them online and they mailed me a replacement. The next one will expire at the end of October. I wasn't sure when I'd get the replacement so I wrote to their online support asking when I should expect the replacement. In their response, they said they've "handled my replacement card request and I should expect one in the next few days." Does this mean they only sent me a card because I asked about it or are my two issues just glitches?

When your card is going to expire, when should you approximately receive a new one or must you contact the bank?

Comment: Usually it is automatic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They should send you the new card about 30-60 days before the expiration. I've never heard of a case where you actually need to ask for it to happen, it should be done automatically. The card expiration is a security feature, it's not the end of the contract between you and the credit card company where they "need to think about it" whether to send you a new one.

Check if the original card was lost (or worse - stolen) while en route.

Comment: Yea, make sure they didn't send it and you just didn't receive it. Sounds weird.

Answer (score 5):

Never. Well, maybe if you don't use the card, they may quietly not bother to send new ones, but typically they'll send replacement cards 2-3 weeks before expiration. I've never had to call to get the cards replaced unless I lost them.

Answer (score 5):

If it's in the expiration month and you haven't received the replacement card yet, then contact them. They should send it out, but there is always a chance that someone stole it.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is 4 year old thread. But for future reference, my bank did not send me new card after expiry and when I checked with them agent said this due to inactivity of the account. He said it is like 6 month/1 year of activity.

Comment: Thanks! This might help other people understand why they didn't get a replacement too.